# How can i format all phone numbers in json array before returning it

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have json data which i get from an API which has phone numbers in an array of objects. What i need to do is format those nbrs.

here is a sample of the data i get from the api i call and which i want to transform.

```
[
    {
         "Name": "Tom Miller",
         "emails": [
             {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
             {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
        ],
         "phones": [
             {"fax": 2015551212},
             {"home": 2134441212},
             {"mobile": 3105551212},
             {"work": 3605551212}
        ]
    },
    {
         "Name": "Bud Light",
         "emails": [
             {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
             {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
        ],
         "phones": [
             {"fax": 2015551212},
             {"home": 2134441212},
             {"mobile": 3105551212},
             {"work": 3605551212}
        ]
    }
]
```

i want to be able to tale each phone nbr in the phones array and call a function to format the nbr and then replace the nbr with the newly formatted nbr before i return it to my app.

the function i call to format nbrs is like this

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '')
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
  if (match) {
    return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3]
  }
  return phoneNumberString
}
```

how can i do this ?

here is what i am trying to return based on my function

```
[

        {
             "Name": "Tom Miller",
             "emails": [
                 {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
                 {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
            ],
             "phones": [
                 {"fax": "(201) 555-1212"},
                 {"home": "(213) 444-1212"},
                 {"mobile": "(310) 555-1212"},
                 {"work": "(360) 555-1212"}
            ]
        },
        {
             "Name": "Bud Light",
             "emails": [
                 {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
                 {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
            ],
             "phones": [
                 {"fax": "(201) 555-1212"},
                 {"home": "(213) 444-1212"},
                 {"mobile": "(310) 555-1212"},
                 {"work": "(360) 555-1212"}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please add your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var defaultArray = [
    {
         "Name": "Tom Miller",
         "emails": [
             {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
             {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
        ],
         "phones": [
             {"fax": 2015551212},
             {"home": 2134441212},
             {"mobile": 3105551212},
             {"work": 3605551212}
        ]
    },
    {
         "Name": "Bud Light",
         "emails": [
             {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
             {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
        ],
         "phones": [
             {"fax": 2015551212},
             {"home": 2134441212},
             {"mobile": 3105551212},
             {"work": 3605551212}
        ]
    }
]

function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '')
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
  if (match) {
    return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3]
  }
  return phoneNumberString
} 

for(let item of defaultArray){
for(let phoneItems in item.phones){
let currentVal = Object.keys(item.phones[phoneItems])[0];
item.phones[phoneItems] = formatPhoneNumber(item.phones[phoneItems][currentVal])
}
}

console.log(defaultArray)
```

Please use the below code. Let me know these are the expected output.

```
var defaultArray = [
{
     "Name": "Tom Miller",
     "emails": [
         {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
         {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
    ],
     "phones": [
         {"fax": 2015551212},
         {"home": 2134441212},
         {"mobile": 3105551212},
         {"work": 3605551212}
    ]
},
{
     "Name": "Bud Light",
     "emails": [
         {"primary": "email1@test.com"},
         {"secondary": "email2@test.com"}
    ],
     "phones": [
         {"fax": 2015551212},
         {"home": 2134441212},
         {"mobile": 3105551212},
         {"work": 3605551212}
    ]
}
]

    function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '')
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
  if (match) {
    return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3]
  }
  return phoneNumberString
}



for(let item of defaultArray){
    for(let phoneItems in item.phones){
       let currentVal = Object.keys(item.phones[phoneItems])[0];
           item.phones[phoneItems] = formatPhoneNumber(item.phones[phoneItems][currentVal])
    }
}
```